# Using Cursor for updating nested tables pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having nested table

```
create or replace type comm_type as object
 (comm_month varchar(5),
 comm_amount  number); 

create or replace TYPE comm_array AS VARRAY(12) OF comm_type;

alter table emp2 add commission comm_array
```

Now the question is how I can update `comm_amount` column using a **cursor**?

For now, I have this, but I cannot get the access to the sub table (commission, any suggestions?

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR c_comm_amount_cursor IS 
   select c.comm_amount
    from emp2 e, table (e.commission) c
    where c.comm_month = 'DEC' for update of c.comm_month nowait;
BEGIN
   FOR emp_record IN c_comm_amount_cursor LOOP
    UPDATE emp2
     SET  emp2.commission.comm_amount = emp2.commission.comm_amount + 100
     WHERE CURRENT OF c_emp_cursor;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**EDIT**

Here is the desc of my table:

```
Name       Null?    Type         
---------- -------- ------------ 
EMPNO      NOT NULL NUMBER(4)    
ENAME               VARCHAR2(10)    
BONUS               NUMBER       
COMMISSION          COMM_ARRAY

comm_array->12*times(comm_month, comm_amount)
```

ANd I want to update comm_amount in a specific month.

**SOLUTION**

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR c_comm_amount_cursor IS 
   select c.comm_amount,c.comm_month, e.empno
    from emp2 e, table (e.commission) c
    where c.comm_month = 'DEC'for update of c.comm_month nowait;

BEGIN
  FOR emp_record IN c_comm_amount_cursor 
  LOOP
     UPDATE table(Select commission from emp2 where empno = emp_record.empno) e 
     SET  e.comm_amount = e.comm_amount + 100
     WHERE CURRENT OF c_comm_amount_cursor;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Could you show us the definition and some sample records of `emp2` table? Also, why do you specifically want a cursor loop and not a single update statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few limitation when you use `varrays`. One of them is when you do `DML` operations on table having columns of datatype `varray` like shown in your example. You can use a `Nested table` and achieve your requirement as shown below in my demo. However please bear in mind the nested table operations are quite complicated to understand. See below and read inline comments.

```
--Created Table emp2 with an additional column
CREATE TABLE emp2 (ename VARCHAR2(10));

--Object 
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE COMM_TYPE AS OBJECT
 (COMM_MONTH VARCHAR(5),
 COMM_AMOUNT  NUMBER); 

--Created a Table of object rather then varray.
CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE COMM_ARRAY AS TABLE OF COMM_TYPE;

--Modified table emp2. Added column commission as shown in your example
ALTER  TABLE EMP2 ADD COMMISSION COMM_ARRAY NESTED TABLE COMMISSION STORE AS TBA1;

--Inserted records
INSERT INTO EMP2 VALUES('AAA',COMM_ARRAY(COMM_TYPE('NOV',100)));
INSERT INTO EMP2 VALUES('BBB',COMM_ARRAY(COMM_TYPE('DEC',200)));

--Selected Records
SQL> SELECT C.COMM_AMOUNT,C.COMM_MONTH
  2      FROM EMP2 E, TABLE (E.COMMISSION) C
  3      WHERE C.COMM_MONTH = 'DEC';

COMM_AMOUNT COMM_
----------- -----
        200 DEC
```

--Block to Update records

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR c_comm_amount_cursor IS 
   select c.comm_amount,c.comm_month
    from emp2 e, table (e.commission) c
    where c.comm_month = 'DEC'for update of c.comm_month nowait;
BEGIN
  FOR emp_record IN c_comm_amount_cursor 
  LOOP
     --With the help of table operator you can update records of a nested table but not varray.
     UPDATE table( Select commission from emp2 where ename = 'BBB') e --<--Make sure to use additional column of the table to make unique record selection for update
     SET  e.comm_amount = e.comm_amount + 100    
     WHERE CURRENT OF c_comm_amount_cursor;
 END LOOP;
 COMMIT;
END;
/
```

-- You can see update being done.

```
SQL> /

COMM_AMOUNT COMM_
----------- -----
        300 DEC
```

Also, as mentioned in comments, the use of loop looks redundant and the block can be further simplified as below:

```
BEGIN
     --With the help of table operator you can update records of a nested table but not varray.
 UPDATE table( Select commission from emp2 where ename = 'BBB') e --<--Make sure to use additional column of the table to make unique record selection for update
   SET  e.comm_amount = e.comm_amount + 100    
   WHERE  e.comm_month ='DEC';

 COMMIT;
END;
```

EDIT:

> how can I update every employee, here you choose only one with name
>   'BBB'. Is there a way?

As mentioned in my comments you need can use `dynamic SQL` to update all the employees as show below:

```
DECLARE 
v_sql varchar2(2000);
CURSOR c_enme_cursor IS 
   select ename
    from emp2;
BEGIN
FOR emp_recd IN c_enme_cursor 
LOOP
 v_sql:=q'[
           UPDATE table( Select commission from emp2 where ename = ']'||emp_recd.ename||q'[') e 
             SET  e.comm_amount = e.comm_amount + 100    
            -- WHERE  e.comm_month ='DEC'
          ]';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;          
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: That helped me a lot. I have one more question, how can I update every employee, here you choose only one with name 'BBB'. Is there a way?

Comment: In that case you would need a dynamic sql where each time you would be passing the name at run time. Thats what i said, nesting makes things complicated.

Comment: I just add one more cursor which returns 'empno' and send values to where clause and the thing works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @rubyBeginner. You can see my updated answer as well for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Hi the fast answer is:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR C_COMM_AMOUNT_CURSOR
   IS
      SELECT ROWID ROW_ID
      FROM EMP2 E
      WHERE E.COMM_MONTH = 'DEC';
BEGIN
   FOR EMP_RECORD IN C_COMM_AMOUNT_CURSOR
   LOOP
      UPDATE TABLE (
                    SELECT COMMISSION
                    FROM EMP2
                    WHERE ROWID = ROW_ID
                   )
      SET COMM_AMOUNT = COMM_AMOUNT + 100
      WHERE ;--your where clause condition
   END LOOP;
END;
```

you should know when working with nested tables you have to use **TABLE()** around your nested table in SQL scripts, in PL/SQL it is bit more complicated and you have to create a nested object run time and fill it with your data and manipulate it and later save it on your table which is too far, I have experienced this problem and using **ROWID** was more readable.

Comment: This will not work incase the column is of type `varray` and `CURRENT OF C_EMP_CURSOR;` has to be changed to the cursor name  `C_COMM_AMOUNT_CURSOR` else you will get invalid name error. Your fast answer is really not correct :-)

Comment: Correct this as well `WHERE C.COMM_MONTH = 'DEC';` there is no table with name `c`. Table alias in your example is `E`. And you also cannot get nested table column name as done your example. Please take your time before you share your solution,

Comment: @XING I have tested this code with nested table type and it worked, thanks for your cirrection

Comment: @XING the code has been tested in Oracle 11g and it worked, you have helped with some syntax errors which was corrected, thank you for that, but your idea " you also cannot get nested table column name as done your example" is incorrect, it is possible and correct.